# All contours are not getting converted to shapefile in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to create isoline plot for a weather parameter. Inputs are Lat, Lon and Value. They are read from csv file. When I plot the contours using matplotlib, the code works fine and generates desired output. In addition I want to generate shapefile of this contours instead of image plot. When i tried to generate a shapefile only few of the contour lines are getting written to shapefile.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from shapely.geometry import mapping, Polygon, LineString,MultiLineString
import fiona

# set up plot
plt.clf()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='w', frame_on=False)


# grab data
data = pd.read_csv('Filename.csv', sep=',')
norm = Normalize()

# define map extent
lllon = -180
lllat = -90
urlon = 180
urlat = 90

# Set up Basemap instance
m = Basemap(#projection = 'merc',llcrnrlon = lllon, llcrnrlat = lllat, urcrnrlon = urlon, urcrnrlat = urlat,resolution='h', epsg=4326)
# transform lon / lat coordinates to map projection
data['projected_lon'], data['projected_lat'] = m(*(data.CLON.values, data.CLAT.values))
# grid data
numcols, numrows = 100, 100
xi = np.linspace(data['projected_lon'].min(),data['projected_lon'].max(), numcols)
yi = np.linspace(data['projected_lat'].min(),data['projected_lat'].max(), numrows)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

# interpolate
x, y, z = data['projected_lon'].values, data['projected_lat'].values, data.PRES.values
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)


# contour plot
cs = plt.contour(xi, yi, zi,zorder=4)
plt.show()

#Create a shapefile of contours with linestring
lenvar = (len(cs.collections))   #number of contours
print(lenvar)
lines = []  # Empty list for contour sections

for i in range(lenvar):
  n = i
  p = cs.collections[i].get_paths()[0]
  v = p.vertices # getting the individual verticies as a numpy.ndarray
  x = v[:,0] #takes first column
  y = v[:,1] #takes second column
  line = LineString([(i[0], i[1]) for i in zip(x,y)])  #Defines Linestring
  lines.append(line) #appends to list

schema = {'geometry': 'LineString','properties': {'id': 'int'}}  # sets up parameter for shapefile

 with fiona.open('ConShp.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as c:  # creates new file to be written to
 for j in range(len(lines)):
  l = (lines[j])   # creates variable
  print(l)
  print(type(l))
  c.write({'geometry': mapping(l),'properties': {'id': j},})
```

[image: Shp_Contour_PLot]
[image: SLP_Plot_from_python]

I want to generate SHP file similar to plot file generated by python matplotlib.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is just a copy/paste issue, but your indentation is off on the last block where you're writing to shapefile.